# How to limit Previous/Older and Next/Newer links on a post page to specific labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, blogger, blogspot

Blogger has a simple post navigation, older & newer posts or prev & next posts, 
which displays all posts in a row.

```
<div class='blog-pager' id='blog-pager'>
   <b:if cond='data:newerPageUrl'>
      <span id='blog-pager-newer-link'>
         <a class='blog-pager-newer-link' expr:href='data:newerPageUrl' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_blog-pager-newer-link&quot;' expr:title='data:newerPageTitle'>
            <data:newerPageTitle/>
         </a>
      </span>
   </b:if>
   <b:if cond='data:olderPageUrl'>
      <span id='blog-pager-older-link'>
         <a class='blog-pager-older-link' expr:href='data:olderPageUrl' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_blog-pager-older-link&quot;' expr:title='data:olderPageTitle'>
            <data:olderPageTitle/>
         </a>
      </span>
   </b:if>
</div>
```

I need what this navigation display next and prev posts by labels, for example as related posts widget display only that posts, which belong to the categories of this post.

I found some scripts, but all of them not working. Does anybody know, how to resolve this problem?